# Technologies for writing a web Paint program

Tags: javascript, web-applications, drawing, paint

I would like to do a a web Paint program. 
Basically I would like to mimic the Windows Paint program in a web application.

The features that I don't really know how to implement are:

1. the drawing of 2D shapes (line, circle, etc) in a web browser
2. drag and drop
3. resize dynamically (seeing preview as you are moving the mouse for resizing)

I am guessing there will be HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript. I am mainly wondering if there are Javascript libraries that I could use to make my life easier.

Best regards

Comment: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript_graphics_library) has a slew of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you want to use canvas (the 'new flash'). It is a HTML5 element widely supported in newer (mobile) browsers.

Here are some links to get you started:
[a complete ms-paint copy salvaged from the archive (last one I could find)](http://web.archive.org/web/20111127134327/http://canvaspaint.org/)
http://mudcu.be/sketchpad/
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355230/HTML-5-Canvas-A-Simple-Paint-Program-Touch-and-Mou

Some popular library's are:
[fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/), [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/) and [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/)

Good luck!

Comment: I ended up using Fabric.js. It's very easy to use, and the code is really well written, enabling easy customization for the code base for your own goals. I was happy to use it for my project and recommend to anyone starting with drawing on the web.